# Similar way to make a installer in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield

I saw that my Visual Studio 2015 does not have the "Setup and Deployment" option to make an installer and read in other questions and articles that InstallShield is not available in Visual Studio 2015 so I want to know if there is some similar way to make a installer (easy and complete) or if there is a way to use again Install Shield in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The answer may depend on the edition of Visual Studio 2015 that you are using; not all extensions are available for the community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's preferred replacement seems to be http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: I don't think one can say that's an official MSFT recommendation as they do also have a partnership with Flexera for InstallShield Limited Edition.  But the force is certainly strong for WiX inside Redmond for sure.

Comment: I personally don't enjoy trying to "program" an installer in XML syntax, which is what using straight WiX amounts to, last I tried. (It's really more "declarative" than coding)  However... keeping with the WiX recommendation, there is an open source tool that allows you to use C# code as the "UI" to generate the XML code for your WiX installers.  I've used it and it works just fine for many things.  As a front end to WiX, the resulting output is a WiX-based installer MSI.  This tool., known as WixSharp, aka "Wix#", can be found here: https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp

Comment: See also my comment re InstallShield LE 2017 on @ChristopherPainter 's answer for a scenario where the InstallShield LE product worked very well for me. It's about finding the right fit of tool for the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the project type you mentioned was made available again as an AddOn. I don't personally recommend it but here it is:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

I don't know what your projects needs are and we aren't supposed to get into the whole this tool or that tool thing here but personally I'd look at the following and decide for yourself.

Windows Installer XML (WiX) / Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML (IsWiX)*

InstallShield Limited Edition

Advanced Installer

InstallShield Professional

*Disclaimer: My open source project that accelerates WiX development. Here are some simple demos:

Desktop Application
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnV_OU6fk8c

64bit Desktop Application
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn7PyKfZwn4

Windows Service
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxbcPnjfzIc

IIS WebSite
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDf1kv8a-4

Comment: I DO recommend the updated "InstallShield LE 2017" Visual Studio add-on for *SOME* types of installers.  For several recent .NET client ClickOnce installers, I wound up using the InstallShield LE 2017 product along with VS2015, because InstallShield LE handled the COM extraction to build the installer, plus COM registrations on the target system. It did a rather nice job at this, actually.  InstallShield LE was easy to learn and worked well. Never thought I'd be giving them a testimonial, I've not previously liked their offerings, but IS LE 2017 has been great for the above scenario.

Comment: COM is a little bit harder using WiX/IsWiX.  Basically you follow the desktop application recipe and then use Heat to harvest the COM meta data.  Problem is the directory/component/file id's in the fragments won't match what IsWiX authored so you have to copy/paste transplant the elements from the heat wxs to the IsWiX wxs  and massage the [DIR]/[#filekey]  references to match.   It's not too hard once you've done it a couple times but it is a pain.  It's bulletproof reliable from there though.  I'm not sure how to automate that in an IsWiX designer and it's rarely needed so I didn't do it.